# Anonymity / free vs trust

Tags: web-app, login, web, payment, privacy

This is a two-part question.  I'm going to pick on Craigslist, but I think it applies to other sites as well.

One of the drawbacks to free/anonymous posting is the amount of spam (including mass-posting across inappropriate categories), scams and phishing. This problem seems to be getting worse, and some sites have even disabled anonymous commenting to combat trolling.

Would a post/ad on a site that required registration with a real name (even if it wasn't visible) be more trustworthy? Would you be more inclined to trust an ad that was paid for (even a nominal fee)?

Second part: Do you think people would be willing to use such a site? Willing to pay a small fee to post ads? Or are people overall willing to put up with the garbage in exchange for anonymity/free? (Obviously people still use Craigslist, but if an alternative were available, would they use it)

Comment: This is a pretty broad and subjective question. Whether people would use a website depends entirely on too many things for anybody to accurately say yes or no.

Comment: @KevinWorkman No one is suggesting comparing craigslist to Kijiji or any other popular classified ads site.  The choice is between identical sites except for the fact that SiteB has slightly different rules for posting advertisements.  Do you trust SiteA or SiteB more?

Comment: Again, it depends entirely on a bunch of other things. And even if *I* trusted SiteA more, that doesn't mean anybody else will trust it more. It depends on a lot of things, including the look and feel of the website, the established userbase, past history, etc. Asking "would people use this?" isn't really a question anybody can answer.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I agree that it's a broad question, and subjective. While look and feel are very important aspects of a website's usability, so is content, and so I was wondering if there was anything to that, or if most people don't care as much about that part of the experience. As for the second question, that was really about the extent to  which people care. If this is not the right place for this question, leave a comment and I'll close it. thanks

Comment: I don't know where the question belongs, but the lack of answers and votes might show you that the question is too broad to answer. It's like asking "if I opened a restaurant like restaurant X but with features XYZ, would people eat there?" - it's not really something strangers on the internet can answer. It depends on a lot of things that you can't really know until you actually build the thing, which is why it's so hard to land on a successful combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, if I find a site that doesn't require registration but has reasonable content, I'll use that site. Why? Well, that's the important part. As you mention and we all know, is very common to have garbage all over the Internet, and paid sites are no exception, you just have different garbage, but if a specially prone to garbage site is clean, that means that the community/moderators/administrators are keeping a close an eye on it an are able to keep it that way; that's a site I'll get involved with.

Of course the clean up part may be done with a clever programming. But humans have to be involved.

Is what I propose above viable? Yes it is. Is it easy? No it's not. Would that work for a big site like Craiglist? Most probably no, but I can't tell. Would that work for a small site? Yes it would, most probably, specially if you start from the beginning.